# In Ethereum private network public IP node and private IP node peer is possible?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, peers

In Ethereum private network one node in AWS EC2 instance with public IP and another is in local machine with private IP. Is is possible to peer this two node using boot node. Is it possible to peer? If possible then how?

Comment: There's the `TrustedNodes` and `StaticNodes` in config.toml. Have you tried that?